# Given ΔABC with sides a,b,c and circumradius R. Prove this...

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

Given $\triangle ABC$ with sides $a,b,c$ and circumradius $R$. Prove that

$$\cot A+ \cot B +\cot C= \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{abc}R$$

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: You can prove that using the law of sines and the law of cosines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sin and Cosine formulas for all three angles A,B,C. Assuming A,B,C are angles opposite to the these sides.

Answer (score 0):

Use $\cos A = \dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}, \sin A = \dfrac{2S}{bc}$ and $abc = 4SR$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\cot A =\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}$,

Because of [cosine theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) 
get $\cos A = \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$

Due to [sine theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) $ \frac{a}{\sin A} = D = 2R $ (where D is the diameter of circumscribed circle of triangle ABC)

=> $ \sin A = \frac{a}{2R}$

=> $\cot A = \frac{\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}}{ \frac{a}{2R}} = \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{abc} \times R $

In the same manner, $\cot B = \frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{abc} \times R $
and  $\cot C = \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{abc} \times R $

Summing up these cotangent items: $\cot A+ \cot B +\cot C= \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{abc}R$

Comment: if it's not too much to ask for, would you be able to structure it a little better like step 1 and 2, etc. It's kinda hard for me to understand.